# Stirling approximation for sum of factorials

Tags: calculus, approximation

I know that the Stirling approximation states that

$$\ln(x!) \approx x\ln x - x$$

However, in some derivations, this is also applied to what looks like a sum of factorial terms. For example, [here](https://bouman.chem.georgetown.edu/S98/boltzmann/boltzmann.htm), which is similar to the derivation in other places, one states that for $W=\frac{N !}{\sum_{i}^{r} n_{i} !}$, we have

$$\ln W=N \ln N-N-\sum_{i}^{r} n_{i} \ln n_{i}-n_{i}$$

How does one show the Stirling approximation for the denominator term of $W$?

Comment: Hint $\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ and $\ln(\frac{a}{b})=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$

Comment: In the linked paper, they write : *the number of microstates is given by the following equation* $W=\frac {N!}{n_0! \,n_1!\,n_2! \cdots}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is wrong.

If the denominator
had product instead of sum,
the formula would be correct.

It doesn't,
so it isn't.